# CircleCI Android constraintLayout doesn't work

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, circleci

I am now using the **CircleCI** for my project. Also I am implementing the new **constraintLayout** in my project. Now I am stuck with the CircleCI building. It shows me this when **gradle -dependencies** run:

```
File /home/ubuntu/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3, com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.0-alpha3].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html
```

Here is my configuration in .yml file:

```
#Install android build tools, platforms
#Supported versions here https://circleci.com/docs/android
machine:
    java:
        version: openjdk8
    environment:
        ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux

dependencies:
    pre:
        - echo y | android list sdk
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "tools"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "platform-tools"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-24.0.0"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-24"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-m2repository"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-google-google_play_services"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-support"
        - echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
        - (./gradlew -version):
                    timeout: 360
    override:
        #- ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux ./gradlew dependencies
        - export TERM="dumb"; if [ -e ./gradlew ]; then ./gradlew clean dependencies -stacktrace;else gradle clean dependencies -stacktrace;fi

#Pull any submodules
checkout:
  post:
    - git submodule init
    - git submodule update

#-PdisablePreDex is a must else gradle just dies due to memory limit
#Replace
test:
    override:
        - (./gradlew assemble -PdisablePreDex):
            timeout: 360
        - cp -r ${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/app/build/outputs/apk/ $CIRCLE_ARTIFACTS
        - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
            background: true
            parallel: true
        # wait for it to have booted
        - circle-android wait-for-boot
        # run tests  against the emulator.
        - ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest

#Deploy when tests pass
deployment:
    #production:
    #    branch: master
    #    commands:
    #        - (./gradlew clean assembleRelease crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease -PdisablePreFex):
    #            timeout: 720

    staging:
        branch: staging
        commands:
             - (./gradlew clean assembleStaging crashlyticsUploadDistributionStaging -PdisablePreFex):
                timeout: 720
```

I checked in the build log when

```
echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"
```

command run and here is the result:

```
November 20, 2015
Do you accept the license 'android-sdk-license-c81a61d9' [y/n]: 
Installing Archives:
  Preparing to install archives
  Downloading Android Support Repository, revision 33
  Installing Android Support Repository, revision 33
    Installed Android Support Repository, revision 33
  Done. 1 package installed.
```

And my classpath is:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha4'
```

I am not sure what I've done incorrectly or is there anything I need to add more. Please suggest.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You need to copy the licenses from `$ANDROID_HOME/licenses` into your CircleCI environment.

You can zip up your licenses and store it on Dropbox (or something similar) and modify your `circle.yml` file to download the licenses and extract it to `$ANDROID_HOME`.

The last paragraph of the error pretty much explains it

> Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager. Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

Comment: Thanks, I finally found the way to export the License to CI by adding these to dependencies pre:
 - cp -r ${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/android-sdk-license $ANDROID_HOME
        - cp -r ${HOME}/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/android-sdk-preview-license $ANDROID_HOME

Also I put android-sdk-license and android-sdk-preview-license in my repo

Comment: This is a great tip! But I would suggest putting the content of the `android-sdk-license` and `android-sdk-preview-license` as two separate Circle CI environment variables instead, as the env vars are protected, which isn't necessarily true for your VCS repo.

Comment: @Jutikorn where can i download that also? I only found `android-sdk-license`

Answer (score 3):

Alex Fu's answer explains nicely where the problem lies and how to deal with it but there is a simpler solution. Since the license files are really just simple files with a bunch of hex characters in them you can create them simply without any copying. An example would be putting the following code into the `pre:` section:

```
- ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/android-sdk-linux
- mkdir "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses" || true
- echo "8933bad161af4178b1185d1a37fbf41ea5269c55" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-license"
- echo "84831b9409646a918e30573bab4c9c91346d8abd" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/android-sdk-preview-license"
- echo "d975f751698a77b662f1254ddbeed3901e976f5a" > "$ANDROID_HOME/licenses/intel-android-extra-license"
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, and also checks for cached versions first:

```
dependencies:
  pre:
    # Android SDK Platform 24
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-24" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "android-24"; fi
    # Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24.0.1
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "build-tools-24.0.1"; fi
    # Android Support Repository, revision 35 / Local Maven repository for Support Libraries
    - if [ ! -d "/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/24.1.0" ]; then echo y | android update sdk --no-ui --all --filter "extra-android-m2repository"; fi


  cache_directories:
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-24
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/24.0.1
    - /usr/local/android-sdk-linux/extras/android/m2repository
```

Taken from [this post](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/android-sdk-support-library-24/5247/4) by CircleCI employee **drazisil**

Answer (score 2):

I have same issue with `ConstraintLayout`, this is my working config [circle.yml](https://gist.github.com/Tadas44/206dc69ba5a9c5ac946a1c3fe22d23a4)

Comment: I am using your .yml file but still have the same problem

Comment: Finally it worked. I have copied the licenses folder and it worked :)